# Looking for a Solvent for Fragrance Oils

Tags: solvents

Hi I am looking for a solvent for fragrance oils, that has low evaporation and high diffusivity (low molecular weight and hence spreads well in the air). The solvent should also be soluble in water and should have a low evaporation rate (I tried methanol, it diffuses well but it evaporates very fast, thus not serving the purpose)

Comment: Possibly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/4927/194